# Changing header names in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have some code which imports a CSV file into a database, but having some trouble with in place changes because of attribute names not matching up.

The headers in the CSV file look like this:

```
Date,Visitors
02/01/2014,3483
01/01/2014,13636
```

My database has the same fields but they don't use capital letters at the beginning:

```
date
visitors
```

When I import the file it works great but I have to manually edit the values in the file and change the headers to lowercase so they match on the import. Here is my import method in my model:

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      entry = find_by(date: Date.parse(row["Date"])) || new
      entry.update row.to_hash
      entry.save!
    end
end
```

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to make my method change the header names in the hash before it gets into the database and fails, so I can remove some of the manual intervention of editing the file myself.

I've tried looking into the .slice method but they look as though it's only for selecting specific attributes, I've found some pure ruby using the .map to replace these but wondering if rails includes something more suited to this task?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You want to change headers fields in lowercase? Is this your need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add one option as `:header_converters => [:downcase]`. Once you will add this option, it calls `String#downcase` method on the header String.

Look at the below code to give you the hints :

```
require 'csv'

str = <<_
Date,Visitors
02/01/2014,3483
01/01/2014,13636
_

File.write('a',str)

CSV.foreach('a',:headers => true,:header_converters => [:downcase]) do |row|
  p row.to_hash
end
# >> {"date"=>"02/01/2014", "visitors"=>"3483"}
# >> {"date"=>"01/01/2014", "visitors"=>"13636"}
```

so, your method would be :

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach( file.path, headers: true, :header_converters => [:downcase] ) do |row|
      entry = find_by(date: Date.parse(row["date"])) || new
      entry.update row.to_hash
      entry.save!
    end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me? I get 'no implicit conversion of nil into String' complaining now about the line: entry = find_by(date: Date.parse(row["Date"])) || new .. any ideas?

Comment: Ah yes of course! It wouldn't have worked after it was being changed. I should have spotted that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No need for nothing fancy, just manipulate the hash before calling `#update`:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    entry = find_by(date: Date.parse(row["Date"])) || new

    attributes = row.to_hash
    attributes[:visitors] = attributes.delete("Visitors")
    attributes[:date]     = attributes.delete("Date")

    entry.update(attributes)
    entry.save!
  end
end
```

`Hash#delete` removes the entry from the hash and returns its value. I chose to delete it to avoid having both attributes (i.e. `"Visitors"` and `"visitors"`) on the hash.

In case there are more attributes on the CSV and you don't want to list them one by one, you might want to go with a slightly more robust solution:

```
CSV_MAP = {
  'Date'     => 'date',
  'Visitors' => 'visitors',
  # More attributes...
}

def update_with_csv_row(row)
  attributes = CSV_MAP.each_with_object({}) do |(csv_key, attribute_key), result|
    result[attribute_key] = row[csv_key]
  end

  update(attributes)
end
```

Then, just call `#update_with_csv_row` instead of `#update` on your original code.

Comment: This is really useful thank you! I can see myself needing this information in the future, great for reference.